# Reloading page via the reload button or the site logo?

Tags: google-chrome

Occasionally, I have browsers/searchers block and I'll sit on the frontpage of Stack Exchange sites waiting for something to pop up... reloading the page every now and again.

[image] Vs. [image]

Is there a difference between the two?

- I get the feeling clicking the SE page logo reloads less?
- When using the browser reload, it takes slightly longer and completely redraws the page.

Is one less load on the server or a preferred method to reload/refresh the frontpage?

Comment: *Hammer* the frontpage? Huh...how about a bash script which downloads the site with wget, parses it with grep/sed/awk for question titles and displays them to you in real time? \*eg\* Not that we misunderstand each other...I'd write you such a beast...

Comment: Observation with FF9 is that the "Reload" button does load some other resources anew.

Comment: This has to do with browser implementation, not with the Stack Exchange sites. Clicking the logo affords the browser the opportunity to draw resources directly from cache based on information it already has, so if you're worried about sending pointless requests (i.e. those that return 304 Not Modified) to the CDN then click the logo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how browsers work not about a specific web app.

Comment: Migrated from Meta by @JeffAtwood ... I think he knows what's on/off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally be clicking on the site logo rather than hitting the reload button.

In almost every browser, the reload button will invalidate locally cached copies of *everything* on the page (including images, CSS, and plenty of other static content that won't have changed).  This will cause unnecessary load on the site (or, if they are lucky, some intermediate caching proxy).

Clicking on the site logo will just reload the current URL (assuming you are viewing the site's main page) and will generally cause just a few (possibly just one) HTTP GET request.